# How can I access a picture that was texted to me?

Tags: sms, pictures

I got a text with a picture attached. I can see the picture, but I can't seem to save it or access it any other way. Say I wanted to get it to my PC, how can I do that?

This is a Lumia 920 with the fake carrier "Developer Device" (and a real SIM from a real carrier) on Windows Phone 8.1. Specifically 8.10.12393.890

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you open the MMS (photo in SMS), you should be seeing your photo in seperate screen with Save button in the App bar. Clicking on Save will save it to Saved pictures. From there you may goto Pictures, and tap the photo and click on Share button on App bar to share it via Email/any other messaging apps/upload to OneDrive.

Comment: Ah, that was the trick! I tapped (possibly double tapped) on the picture in the text, which brought the picture up full screen. Then a swipe for the app bar and I see a Save icon. (I could share from this page btw.) Now it is in Saved Pictures. Thanks!